# Using OSM and EPSG:4326 with openlayers increase latitude in near 90 degrees. Why?

Tags: coordinates, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using openLayers and creating a OSM base layer. By default the layer use EPSG:900913 and the coordinates are in meters. I want to use coordinates in degrees with EPSG:4326 so I initilize layer with:

```
base_layer.addOptions({ sphericalMercator: true, 
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')}, true);
```

Now the map uses degrees but have the next problem: The point with latitude 37.296 and longitude -5.929 (http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=37.296&lon=-5.929&zoom=12&layers=Q# and the same coordinates in Google Maps) appears to me (moving map and executing `map.getCenter()` in firebug) in lat. -49.75, lon. -5.929.

Why? How can I use an OSM layer with same degrees coordinates as in `openstreetmap.org` and as are returned by `nominatim.openstreetmap.org`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just claim the layer is `EPSG:4326` when the tiles you are displaying are actually rendered in `EPSG:3857`. That is nonsensical.

I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to do here to be honest, but it may help to set `displayProjection` to `EPSG:4326` which will cause OpenLayers to use degrees when it is communicating values to/from the user.

If you want to to read or set the map location in code then you will need to reproject the value you get from `getCenter` or give to `setCenter` yourself by calling the `transform` method on the location value.

Comment: I see. I thought that if I declared EPSG:4226 openLayers would transform coordinates instead of having to do it by my self. Transform explicitly every coordinates any time I use set/getCenter should not be needed.